# Heads up with reply (RemoteInput) does not cancel notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

Step1 : Build Notification with Reply intent and heads up notification

```
  private void buildInlineReplyNotification() {
    // Create an instance of RemoteInput.Builder that you can add to your notification action.
    // This class's constructor accepts a string that the system uses as the key for the text input.
    // Later, your handheld app uses that key to retrieve the text of the input.
    RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(KEY_TEXT_REPLY).setLabel(
        getResources().getString(R.string.reply_label)).build();

    // Attach the RemoteInput object to an action using addRemoteInput().
    NotificationCompat.Action compatAction =
        new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.mipmap.ic_reply,
            getResources().getString(R.string.reply), replyPendingIntent).addRemoteInput(
            remoteInput).setAllowGeneratedReplies(true).build();

    // Build the notification and add the action.
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(
                getResources().getString(R.string.notification_created) + mNotificationId)
            .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.type_reply))
            .setShowWhen(true)
            .addAction(compatAction);

    mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH).setVibrate(new long[0]);

    // Issue the notification.
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
  }
```

Step2 : cancel after reply from notification

```
private void updateNotification(Context context, int notifyId) {
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification)
            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.message_sent));

    notificationManager.cancel(notifyId);
  }
```

Issues is not cancel notification by **notificationManager.cancel(notifyId)** but if i remove this **mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH).setVibrate(new long[0]);** Than work perfect so, what is issue with priority in notification ?

Comment: Any update on this issue? 
I'm having the same problem.

Comment: A couple of workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54219914/cancel-notification-with-remoteinput-not-working)