# cancel notification with remoteInput not working

Tags: android, android-notifications, remote-input

I am showing a notification with `RemoteInput` like this:

```
   RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder("key_add_note")
                .setLabel("add note")
                .build();


        PendingIntent AddNotePendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
                        (int) txn.get_id(),
                        new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddNoteBroadcastReceiver.class)
                                .putExtra(Constants.IntentExtras.STA_TXN_ID, txn.get_id()),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Action action =
                new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_action_edit_dark,
                        "add note", AddNotePendingIntent)
                        .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                        .build();


        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NotificationUtil.MISC_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("TEST")
                .setContentText("add Note")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_edit_dark)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .addAction(action);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(123456, builder.build());
```

output:

[image: notification]

after clicking on add note, entering text and submitting it I try to cancel notification like this:

```
notificationManager.cancel(123456);
```

which does not cancel notification but just dismiss the input field with text appended below my notification like this:

[image]

why does this not cancel the notification? and how to cancel it.

update: same results even there is a tag with notification

Comment: Please let me know if this particular answer (to a similar question) works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20007350/2710385

Comment: @dylan-myers No, It doesn't.

Comment: Having the same issue, also using custom int tags (not 1). Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: I was not able to resolve it while working on this project.

Answer (score 3):

After a while, I found a workaround, definitely not the most elegant solution. Issue happens for me on Android 9, whereas the notification with remote input is made undismissable by the system. The workaround is, after the user enters the text and clicks, and we need to [update the notification UI](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#retrieve-user-reply), to use `setTimeoutAfter()`; even with values as low as 1 millisecond, the notification is removed after few seconds, so the solution is not the best.

```
fun updateNotification(context: Context, id: Int) {
    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, MY_CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_action_edit_dark)
        .setContentText(MY_TEXT)
        .setTimeoutAfter(1)
        .build()

    // show notification. This hides direct reply UI
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(id, notification)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I create a notification with an opportunity to answer inside of it (as in the [example](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification) with `RemoteInput`) and want to do **NOT REPLACE** it with other notification after the answer:

```
notificationManager.notify(tag, requestCode, notification);
```

but just to **CANCEL** it right after the answer with

```
notificationManager.cancel(tag, requestCode);
```

it does not disappear from the notification panel.

More over when I try to find out a list of existing notifications AFTER above cancel with

```
StatusBarNotification[] barNotifications = notificationManager.getActiveNotifications();
```

this (still not disappeared from the notification panel) notification **IS ABSENT** int the list!!

This **bug appears starting from API 29** only and does not depend am I answering from the notification panel or from the "heads-up" notification.

As a workaround I have to replace an answered notification as in the [manual](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification) with `RemoteInput`)

```
notificationManager.notify(tag, requestCode, notification);
```

wait a couple seconds

```
Thread.sleep(2000)
```

and cancel it after

```
notificationManager.cancel(tag, requestCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a tag to your notification and then provide that tag while you perform cancel as following:

While creating(Replace my_tag with your preferred unique tag):

```
notificationManager.notify("my_tag",123456, builder.build());
```

While canceling:

```
notificationManager.cancel("my_tag",123456);
```

Comment: It [does not work](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159152393)